# How to add a subitem in this list activity?

Tags: android, listview, text, subitem

i wanna add subitem for every list item.I am working on an app which uses swipey tabs in one tab there is a list and following is the code for that list i just wanna add a subitem text to every list entry how can i do that.

```
public class FragmentCommandList extends SherlockFragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the list fragment and add it as our sole content.
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content) == null) {
        ArrayListFragment list = new ArrayListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();
    }
}

public static class ArrayListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

    public static String[] data = {"First", "Second", "third"};
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
               android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change you ListFragment to a fragment with an `Expandable ListView`.
For example:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/10/android-expandablelistview-example.html

and this:

http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html

Another option you have is to design the layout of the single item of a `ListView` in a way that will allow it to extend. But this would be harder to implement because of the fact that `ListView` `Views` get recycled.